# Automatically grant user group (MediaWiki)

Tags: mediawiki

I’m trying to make it to where if you have over 500 edits and have had an account for 1 month, you are automatically added to a user group. How can I do this?

I tried to use this but it didn’t work:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['extendedconfirmed'] {
    $wgAutoConfirmCount = 500;
    $wgAutoConfirmAge = 30;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable to use for this case is `$wgAutopromote` not `$wgGroupPermissions`.

```
$wgAutoConfirmCount = 500;
$wgAutoConfirmAge = 30;

$wgAutopromote = [
    'extendedconfirmed' => [ '&',
        [ APCOND_EDITCOUNT, null ],
        [ APCOND_AGE, null ],
    ],
];
```

You also have to ensure that you defined what 'extendedconfirmed' user-group is. For that you use `$wgGroupPermissions`